# improvement to my code for Haskell monads

Tags: haskell, monads

I am working with Haskell and maybe monads but I am a little bit confused with them 
here is my code but I am getting error and I do not know how to improve my code.

```
doAdd :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int    
doAdd x y = do 
result <- x + y
return result
```

Comment: It looks like you could just write that function as `doAdd x y = Just (x + y)`.  No need to hit it with a sledgehammer and use do-notation :)

Comment: i wantet to practice do notation ... dude I am learning it

Comment: So, what error do you get?

Comment: In this particular case you have a constructor (Just), it is public (exported from the module), and the relationship between the constructor and return is simple and easy to implement (you know what arguments to pass to the constructor). Hence the advice to use `Just`. Otherwise, you could use `return $ x + y`, no need for `<-`. The use of `<-` makes sense, for example, in `maybeAdd x y = do { xx <- x; yy <- y; return $ xx + yy }`

Answer (score 8):

Let's look critically at the type of the function that you're writing:

```
doAdd :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
```

The point of the `Maybe` monad is to work with types that are *wrapped with* a `Maybe` type constructor.  In your case, the two `Int` arguments are just plain `Int`s, and the `+` function always produces an `Int` so there is no need for the monad.

If instead, your function took `Maybe Int` as its arguments, then you could use `do` notation to handle the `Nothing` case behind the scenes:

```
doAdd :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
doAdd mx my = do x <- mx
                 y <- my
                 return (x + y)

example1 = doAdd (Just 1) (Just 3)   -- => Just 4
example2 = doAdd (Just 1) Nothing    -- => Nothing
example3 = doAdd Nothing (Just 3)    -- => Nothing
example4 = doAdd Nothing Nothing     -- => Nothing
```

But we can extract a pattern from this: what you are doing, more generically, is taking a function (`(+) :: Int -> Int -> Int`) and adapting it to work in the case where the arguments it wants are "inside" a monad.  We can abstract away from the specific function (`+`) and the specific monad (`Maybe`) and get this generic function:

```
liftM2 :: Monad m => (a -> b -> c) -> m a -> m b -> m c
liftM2 f ma mb = do a <- ma
                    b <- mb
                    return (f a b)
```

Now with `liftM2` you can write:

```
doAdd :: Maybe Int -> Maybe Int -> Maybe Int
doAdd = liftM2 (+)
```

The reason why I chose the name `liftM2` is because this is actually a library function—you don't need to write it, you can import the `Control.Monad` module and you'll get it for free.

What would be a better example of using the `Maybe` monad?  When you have an operation that, unlike `+`, can *intrinsically* can produce a `Maybe` result.  One idea would be if you wanted to catch division by 0 mistakes.  You could write a "safe" version of the `div` function:

```
-- | Returns `Nothing` if second argument is zero.
safeDiv :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
safeDiv _ 0 = Nothing
safeDiv x y = Just (x `div` y)
```

Now in this case the monad does become more useful:

```
-- | This function tests whether `x` is divisible by `y`.  Returns `Nothing` if
-- division by zero.
divisibleBy :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Bool
divisibleBy x y = do z <- safeDiv x y
                     let x' = z * y
                     return (x == x')
```

Another more interesting monad example is if you have operations that return more than one value—for example, positive and negative square roots:

```
 -- Compute both square roots of x.
allSqrt x = [sqrt x, -(sqrt x)]

 -- Example: add the square roots of 5 to those of 7.  
example = do x <- allSqrt 5
             y <- allSqrt 7
             return (x + y)
```

Or using `liftM2` from above:

```
example = liftM2 (+) (allSqrt 5) (allSqrt 7)
```

So anyway, a good rule of thumb is this: **never "pollute" a function with a monad type if it doesn't really need it**.  Your original `doAdd`—and even my rewritten version—are a violation of this rule of thumb, because what the function does is adding, but adding has nothing to do with `Maybe`—the `Nothing` handling is just a behavior that we add *on top of* the core function `(+)`.  The reason for this rule of thumb is that any function that does *not* use monads can be generically adapted to add the behavior of any monad you want, using utility functions like `liftM2` (and many other similar utility functions).

On the other hand, `safeDiv` and `allSqrt` are examples where you can't really write the function you want without using `Maybe` or `[]`; *if* you are dealing with a function like that, then monads are often a convenient abstraction for eliminating boilerplate code.

Answer (score 3):

A better example might be

```
justPositive :: Num a => a -> Maybe a
justPositive x
    | x <= 0 = Nothing
    | otherwise = Just x

addPositives x y = do
    x' <- justPositive x
    y' <- justPositive y
    return $ x' + y'
```

This will filter out any non-positive values passed into the function using do notation

Answer (score 1):

That isn't how you'd write that code. The `<-` operator is for getting a value *out* of a monad. The result of `x + y` is just a number, not a monad wrapping a number.

Do notation is actually completely wasteful here. If you were bound and determined to write it that way, it would have to look like this:

```
doAdd x y = do
  let result = x + y
  return result
```

But that's just a longwinded version of this:

```
doAdd x y = return $ x + y
```

Which is in turn equivalent to

```
doAdd x y = Just $ x + y
```

Which is how you'd actually write something like this.

Comment: in here doAdd x y = return $ x + y or doAdd x y = Just $ x + y that you mention you used return and just because of my type signature. Does return do any thing special relating to monad ?

Comment: @user2730833: `return` is a function that wraps a value in a monad. In the case of the Maybe monad, it is equivalent to `Just`. (Literally, the Monad definition for Maybe says `return = Just`.)

Comment: it's not "just wrapping" in a monad, and it's not "just getting value out of a monad". There are monads for which "the wrapping" analogy simply doesn't work. For example, `(->) a` is a monad.

Answer (score 0):

The use case you give doesn't justify do notation, but this is a more common use case-  You can chain functions of this type together.

```
func::Int->Int->Maybe Int -- func would be a function like divide, which is undefined for division by zero

main = do
    result1 <- func 1 2
    result2 <- func 3 4
    result3 <- func result1 result2
    return result3
```

This is the whole point of monads anyway, chaining together functions of type a->m a.

When used this way, the Maybe monad acts much like exceptions in Java (you can use Either if you want to propagate a message up).